# Onclick event needs to click twice?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3

Why do I have to click twice before the background color is set to green?

This is my JavaScript:

```
function OnGroupClicked(groupId) {
  var groupIds = new Array();
  $("#group-name-" + groupId).on("click", function () {
    var body = $('#group-name-div' + groupId),
    green = "rgb(0, 128, 0)",
    white = "rgb(255, 255, 255)";

    if (body.css("background-color") !== green) {
      $('#hidden' + groupId).val(1);
      body.css("background-color", green);
    } else {
      $('#hidden' + groupId).val(0);
      body.css("background-color", white);
    }
  });
}
```

This is my markup:

```
foreach (var group in Model.AllGroups) {    
    if (Model.GroupsForUser.Any(g => g.GroupId == group.GroupId)) { %>
        <div id="group-name-div<%: group.GroupId %>" style="width:auto; height:50px; border:solid 1px black; margin:5px; background-color:green;" >
            <h3>&nbsp; &nbsp; <a href="javascript:OnGroupClicked(<%: group.GroupId %>)" id="group-name-<%: group.GroupId %>"><%: group.Name %></a></h3> 
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" id="hidden<%: group.GroupId %>" name="group-hidden<%: group.GroupId %>" value="" />
    <% } else { %>
        <div id="group-name-div<%: group.GroupId %>" style="width:auto; height:50px; border:solid 1px black; margin:5px;" >
            <h3>&nbsp; &nbsp; <a href="javascript:OnGroupClicked(<%: group.GroupId %>)" id="group-name-<%: group.GroupId %>"><%: group.Name %></a></h3> 
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" id="hidden<%: group.GroupId %>" name="group-hidden-<%: group.GroupId %>" value="" />
    <% }
} %>
```

Comment: Why do you use the `groupId` thing and not just a `this` reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are first declaring the event handler on the first click, not firing it.

To explain further, when you click the link you run the `OnGroupClicked` function, this adds the event listener, but does not fire it.

To get around this, append the event on the element, and use `this` to know what element was clicked.

You could do something like this:

```
$(".changeColor").on("click", function () {
 var body = $(this).closest('group-name-div'),
     green = "rgb(0, 128, 0)",
     white = "rgb(255, 255, 255)";

 if (body.css("background-color") !== green) {
   body.next('input').val(1);
   body.css("background-color", green);
 } else {
   body.next('input').val(0);
   body.css("background-color", white);
 }
});
```

The MVC markup:

```
<div class="group-name-div" id="group-name-div<%: group.GroupId %>">
  <h3><a href="#" class="changeColor"><%: group.Name %></a></h3> 
</div>
<input type="hidden" id="hidden<%: group.GroupId %>" name="group-hidden<%: group.GroupId %>" value="" />
```

You don't need the whole function thing.

Comment: ooo ok any way I can get past this please?

Comment: declare it first, and call it upon the click

Comment: Updated my answer. I hope this will help you more.

Comment: i get an error? The resource cannot be found? Requested URL: /User/Recommend/href=

Comment: This is most likely not this part of your code, look at your console, you should see a 404 error on a resource request.